# What happens if you make a function async and change nothing else?

Tags: javascript, recursion, async-await

I have a sudoku board implemented as an HTML table and a button that when clicked solves the sudoku board using a recursive backtracking algorithm in javascript. Now I want to make it so that you can see the adjustments being made by not altering the HTML immediately in my recursive function. I tried making the function async and then calling this function

`function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}`

like so

```
for (let choice = 1; choice <= 9; choice++) {
      this.boardArray[row][col] = choice;
      // put delay here
      await sleep(250);
      currEntry.textContent = choice;
      if (this.choiceOkay(row, col)) {
        const solved = this.solveBoard(nextRow, nextCol);
        if (solved) {
          return true;
        }
      }
```

This does give me the desired behavior initially but only for a portion of the board and then it seems to just stop. I removed the calls to the sleep function and tried it with the only alteration being "async" in front of the function declaration and it still only did a portion of the board but this time all at once without the visual delay. I'm wondering why making this function async causes this logic error?

Thanks in advance!

Also, this is my first question on Stack Overflow so let me know if I need to be more specific or anything along those lines.

Comment: Can you show us how you are calling your `sleep` function?

Comment: I edited the post to show my sleep function

Answer (score 0):

The [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) keyword in front of a function basically says:

> This function will return a Promise

Your `sleep` function already returns a `Promise`, so writing the keyword `async` is useless.

What matters is the [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) keyword which basically says:

> On my right, there may be an async function (idem a Promise). Wait for my return before continuing

If you write `async function sleep`, but **omit** the `await` keyword when you call `sleep`, you throw the function call in the nature and never waits for its return to come back (hence your code running "without delay")

If you want delay, it is better to let your algorithm be as is, and let the caller of your algorithm tell your algorithm to continue or not.
You can for that matter use [generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator).
(An other possibility could be trampolining).

```js
function* runAlgo () {
  for (let choice = 1; choice <= 9; choice++) {
    yield; // gives control back to delayer
    console.log('choice : ', choice)
    // do your algo and put some yield wherever you like
  }
}
// no need for async, a Promise is already returned
function sleep (t) {
  return new Promise((ok, ko) => setTimeout(ok, t))
}
async function delayer () { // need for async so we can use the await keyword below
  const it = runAlgo()
  let next = it.next()
  while (!next.done) {
    await sleep(1000)
    next = it.next()
  }
}
delayer()
```

---

However, it is very likely that solving your board is what freezes your ui.
So you want to wait inside of solvingBoard as well:

```js
function* solveBoard () {
  let i = 0
  while (i < 5) { //freezes the ui if not yielding
    yield i++
  }
}
function* runAlgo () {
  for (let choice = 1; choice <= 9; choice++) {
    yield 'choice : '+choice; // gives control back to caller
    yield* solveBoard()
  }
}
// no need for async, a Promise is already returned
function sleep (t) {
  return new Promise((ok, ko) => setTimeout(ok, t))
}
async function delayer () { // need for async so we can use the await keyword below
  const it = runAlgo()
  let next = it.next()
  while (!next.done) {
    await sleep(1000)
    next = it.next()
    console.log('data', next.value)
  }
}
delayer()
```

Comment: I will try this!

Comment: Glad to have been of help, happy coding :)